# Put parameter from JavaScript into EL function call in JSF2

Tags: javascript, jsf, el

In JSF2 we can use parameters in EL, which is great. However, I don't know how to use parameters from JavaScript there. This code doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dirty = true
</script>

<h:commandButton value="Back" action="#{bean.setDirty(dirty)}" />
```

Is it possible to add parameters from JavaScript? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Bind a hidden field to the bean and use JavaScript to set the hidden field value. When the request is submitted, the hidden value will be available to your server-side action.